# Blue rendered as purple in Chrome

Tags: multiple-monitors, google-chrome, intel

Sometimes in Google Chrome blue links and buttons are rendered as purple.

Most of the time this happens when both my laptop display and an external monitor are connected at the same time. Sometimes the bug also happens when entering night shift mode and using my laptop display only. If I close the laptop lid and use the external display only, blue is rendered correctly until I close and relaunch Chrome, then it's back to purple.

I've tried removing the color profile setting from Color settings but it has no effect.

My hardware is ThinkPad X250 with Intel HD5500 graphics, HP 24x monitor over DisplayPort using full RGB range (0-255) at 60 Hz or 90 Hz refresh rate. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Chromium 81 from snap and Firefox 76. I'm pretty sure the hardware is fine, Ubuntu is the only OS where I can reproduce this bug. Any ideas?

Here's a pic comparing Chrome and Firefox rendering:

[image: blue as purple]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to work around this by setting `chrome://flags/#force-color-profile` to sRGB and restarting Chrome. Now blue seems to be rendered correctly all the time.

Comment: had exactly the same problem. worked for me too.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!

Comment: Worked for me, thank you!